# How to implement the Command Pattern in a Puzzle Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, command-pattern

**Setup:**
I'm making a classic top-down, tile based puzzle game about pushing blocks and I'm trying to implement the Command Pattern to have a Undo/Redo function. In my design, a "turn" is fired whenever the player moves one tile, and the world must update somehow (lasers can be blocked, Blocks are destroyed if on top of water, Big floor buttons are pressed down, etc.)

I've abstracted my player movement into a Concrete Command `MoveCommand` by simply changing its position based on a direction on execution. This MoveCommand is then instantiated inside a `Move()` method. Blocks also happen to have a `Move()` method that must be called whenever the player "pushes" them (i.e. walks into them and there's a free space behind).

**Question 1.** Should the Block movement be its own Command, or should it be somehow appended to and managed by the player's `MoveCommand`? Right now I figured I would have each be its own separate thing, and then whenever the player presses the Undo button, have the Undo method execute several times until everything that must happen in that turn resolves. However, I'm not sure whether this is how you're supposed to be implementing this pattern.

**Question 2** As mentioned above, blocks must be destroyed when they touch water. Should this destruction be its own `WalkIntoDeadlyTile` Command, or should it be appended to the Block's `MoveCommand`? Both questions make me realize I might not be understanding how to use this pattern, but I'm not sure how to look it up or answer these specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

It is a rare case, where the [ICommand interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand) would not be completely missplaced. You can not keep polling `CanExecute` in most environments. You need a way to force re-evaluation on conditions. Or just use something with binding.

But games are what I call "notorious redrawers" anyway. They could poll `CanExecute` once per draw pass and once in the Input processing pass, without much issues. The check would also be relatively simple (`isPlayerTurn`). The only possible issue is getting teh games state into the Command Implementations.

> Question 2 As mentioned above, blocks must be destroyed when they touch water. Should this destruction be its own WalkIntoDeadlyTile Command, or should it be appended to the Block's MoveCommand?

It should happen in the colission check. A basic square one would work, If the block box collides with the water box, call destroy on the block. This also prevents you from forgetting to add special movement to later blocks or if the blocks *somehow* teleport below water.